# Array_agg From PostgreSQL To Java Array

Tags: java, database, postgresql, intellij-idea, arrayobject

I make a request from Java:

```
  select array_agg(symptoms.*) from symptoms where sickId=1;
```

I get the result:

```
    {(1,"Ларингит острый",t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f)}
```

Then I try to put it all into an array of objects in Java:

```
 Object[] myField = (Object[]) resultSet.getArray("array_agg").getArray();
```

He puts the whole result in the first cell of the array. And I need it to split the result into cells. For example:

```
    myField[0] = 1, myField[1]="Ларингит острый", myField[2] = true  etc
```

How to fix?

I'm trying to get a string from PostgreSQL with a specific index and convert it to an array of Object in Java.

Comment: You can try to iterate through elements of `resultSet.getArray("array_agg").getArray();` and extract it to another array

Comment: @Bonniu I think about it. I try to `myField.toString()` and `String.valueOf(myField)` but it return only  `[Ljava.lang.Object;@15173873`. Tnx for tha answer.

Comment: `myField` is an array, print it in a `for` loop and see what is inside

Comment: @Bonniu                                                                                                                         `for (int j = 0; j < myField.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(myField[j]);
            }`                                                                                                                               Result is `(1,"Ларингит острый",t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f)` because length of myFiels is 1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change your query to return the columns values each one in a row using `unnest` (see doc [9.18. Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html)). Check this example:

Given you have a table like:

| id | type | line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ba4323f9-bf91-4048-98b3-338dd45c810a | PENDENTE | Facetada |
| 4ec17454-9f21-497c-bdc2-53e0951abeb8 | PENDENTE | Cilíndrica |
| 8f7521ab-a559-4e9e-b26f-265d4741e78e | PENDENTE | Cilíndrica |
| bf67f77e-3052-4ea5-bf73-e947c5541f46 | PENDENTE | Cilíndrica |
| 95717728-fd66-4e0d-841c-34dea9246af7 | PENDENTE | Cilíndrica |

When you select your columns as an array and apply `unnest` function to show each column in a row.

```sql
select unnest(array[r.id::text,r.type, r.line]) columns_values from alamar.luminarias as r where id = 'ba4323f9-bf91-4048-98b3-338dd45c810a';
```

Result:

| columns_values |
| --- |
| ba4323f9-bf91-4048-98b3-338dd45c810a |
| PENDENTE |
| Facetada |

Then you can get this results like a array and interact with it

```java
(Object[]) resultSet.getArray("columns_values").getArray();
```